# Prove that $\operatorname{int}(A)$ is a subset of $A'$ (the derived set of $A$)

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove that $\operatorname{int}(A)$ is a subset of $A'$, the derived set of $A$, where $A \subseteq \Bbb{R}$. By definition, I know that an interior point of a set $A$ is a point which is a member of $A$ and if there exists an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that there is a neighborhood which is a subset of the set $A$ or rather $N(x,r)$ where $x$ is the centre point and $r$ is the radius.

I also know that a limit point is a point as it relates to the same set $A$ if every deleted neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $A$. Therefore intuitively I know if you look at a limit point based on the deleted neighborhood there would be points in $A$ which will be contained within that deleted neighborhood such that interior points of $A$ are subsets of the limit point. I'm just confused as to how I show this or rather prove it. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: What kind of space are we working in here? This is not necessarily true in a metric space.

Comment: we havent been introduced to metric spaces so this would not be for a metric space @TheoBendit

Comment: Well, my question would be then, which space are we working in here? Is this just $\Bbb{R}$? A normed linear space?

Comment: @Amir To be more direct, is $A$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}?$... maybe $\mathbb{R}^n?$ (note that both are particularly special metric spaces)

Comment: @BrianMoehring yes A is a subset of R you are correct sorry for not stating that

Comment: @BrianMoehring a subset of R which was stated no mention of R^n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A\subset \Bbb R$.

Let $a\in A^o$.

Then $\exists$ a neighborhood $N_a$ of $a$ such that $N_a\subset A$.

Take an interval $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon) \subset \Bbb N_a$.

Define $a_n=a+1/n$.

For $n\gt 1/\epsilon$, we have $ a_n\in A$.

And clearly $a_n\to a$.

And $a_n\neq a,\forall n$.

$\therefore a\in A'$.

Comment: thank you for the help